# How to stop web page from scrolling down in wordpress?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, elementor

I am newbie. one web page in my project is keeps scrolling down.not automatic but if I am scrolling  down, page is continuously keeping down with white page. I tried to stop this with max-height or overflow css but nothing solve my problem.
Can you pls help me out. Thanks a lot. 
[image: screenshot] 
[specific web page](https://www.8foldlanguage.com/avai-packages/)

Thanks again.

Comment: Did you try to clear your browser cache? Tested on Chrome 68 and latest Safari and can't see the white space after your footer.

Comment: I cleared the browser cache couple of days back. I will check it again now. Thanks for your response.

Comment: I cleared the cache but didn't solve my problem. If I am scrolling it is going down after the footer. Thanks